# How to create static routes for two subnets?

Tags: networking

I have been trying, unsuccessfully, to figure out how to make this work.

I have two network interfaces, and I want to create a static route for each one.

```
10.10.10.0/24 gw 10.10.10.1 
10.167.95.0/26 gw 10.167.95.1
```

Here is my interface configuration:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.167.95.25
    netmask 255.255.255.192
#   gateway 10.167.95.1

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 10.10.10.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.10.10.1
```

How can I create the following static routes:

```
all 0.0.0.0 -> 10.167.95.1 interface
and for 10.0.0.0 -> 10.10.10.1 interface
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by adding the following lines to your /etc/network/interfaces file

```
up route add -net 0.0.0.0/0 gw 10.167.95.1 dev eth0
down route del -net 0.0.0.0/0 gw 10.167.95.1 dev eth0
up route add -net 10.0.0.0/24 gw 10.10.10.1 dev eth0
down route del -net 10.0.0.0/24 gw 10.10.10.1 dev eth0
```

Then restart your networking.

You can find tons of examples here -> http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-add-static-routing/